# Javaでのネットワーク接続での文字列でのgetInputStream使用方法

Tags: java

- 下記のコードでは○×問題（オーとエックス)でしか回答できないようになっています。
- 記述問題を作成したいのですが、getInputStreamのreadをどのように使えばよいか教えていただきたいです。

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO 自動生成されたメソッド・スタブ
        System.out.println("起動完了");
        ServerSocket svSock = null;
        Socket sock = null;
        BufferedWriter w = null;
        try {
            svSock = new ServerSocket(300);
            sock =svSock.accept();
            System.out.println(sock.getInetAddress() + "から接続");
            sock.getOutputStream().write("クイズ出題を開始します\r\n".getBytes("SJIS"));
            //sock.getOutputStream().write("\n".getBytes("SJIS"));
            sock.getOutputStream().write("Javaはコンパイラ言語ですか\r\n".getBytes("SJIS"));
            sock.getOutputStream().flush();
            int ans = sock.getInputStream().read();
            if(String.valueOf((char)ans).equals("o")) {
                sock.getOutputStream().write("\r\n正解".getBytes("SJIS"));
            }else {
                sock.getOutputStream().write("\r\n不正解".getBytes("SJIS"));
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            try {
                sock.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO 自動生成された catch ブロック
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

SO本家の[類似質問](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15480894)のように[BufferedReader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html)と[Socket#getInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jp/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#getInputStream--)を組み合わせて使うと1行分のデータを読み込むことができます。

**サーバ側のサンプルコード** (ご質問にあるMainクラスから抜粋して改変)

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (ServerSocket svSock = new ServerSocket(300);
             Socket sock = svSock.accept();
             //バッファを使って入力を読み込む
             BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()))) {
            //改行コードまでデータ読込
            System.out.println(in.readLine());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

**クライアント側のサンプルコード**

```
import java.net.Socket;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;

public class Sender {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 300);
             OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
             //エンコーディングは任意のものに変えること
             OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(output, "Shift-JIS");
             InputStream input = socket.getInputStream()) {
            String s = "こんにちは, socket!\n";
            for (char ch : s.toCharArray()) {
                writer.write(ch);
            }
            writer.flush();
            //サーバ処理待ちを適当に行う
            int c;
            while ((c = input.read()) != -1) {}
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("occured Exception.");
        }
    }
}
```